# How to connect in full screen mode to Linux CentOS 7 virtual machine?

Tags: centos, screen-resolution, hyper-v

I'm connecting to CentOS 7 VM from Hyper-V from Windows 8.1. The full screen mode is not working. I need to fix that. Other VMs including CentOS 6 and Windows Server have no problems.

These are some observations I made when I connect to that VM from Hyper-V Manager.

1. CentOS 7, while booting, displays this warning "fast TSC calibration failed". I read that this is not a problem but I'm not sure. Everything else is working in the VM except not being able to work in the full screen mode of my laptop which has a pretty high resolution graphics card.
2. Applications -> System Tools -> Settings -> Displays shows only one default option "Built-in Display" with grayed out Resolution of "1152 x 864 (4:3)". This is where I was expecting to see other resolutions to choose from!
3. When I run the following bash command

   ```
   lspci -nn | grep VGA
   ```

I get

```
    00:80.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V Virtual VGA [1414:5353]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

try the following:

```
$sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:2560x1440"
$sudo reboot
```

Also keep in mind that hyperv viewer only goes so far in terms of resolution.
My recommendation, install xrdp and use remote desktop, it's better and you'll get full screen resolution.

Take care.

Comment: Using Centos 7 on Windows 8.1 Hyper-V, this method changed the Hyper-V connection resolution. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. However, I am running CentOS 7 in a Hyper-V VM on Windows 10 Pro (instead of Windows 8.1), so perhaps something in the Win10 version of Hyper-V is preventing this from working? (although I doubt that)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is has been fixed once I have installed below packages on my VM (CentOS 7.6) on Windows 10 host. Hope it may help others too.

```
yum install dkms gcc make kernel-devel bzip2 binutils patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers
```

Later reboot and try to install Virtualbox guest additions.

Take care.