# Can not make ubuntu virtual machine fullscreen

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

i am using windows 8.1 on a 15 inch laptop. I have installed ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on virtual box and have also installed the guest addition.But still i am not getting the "auto-resize guest display "or "seamless mode" option in the view menu?

Comment: Hi, this worked for me..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816916/how-to-connect-in-full-screen-mode-to-linux-centos-7-virtual-machine

edit: Apologies this is for Hyper V not Virtual box

Comment: @ofj i am stll getting errors ......

Comment: What did you try? 
For clarity, this is what worked for me in Centos 7 running on Hyper V. 


$sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL -args="video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"

$sudo reboot


I think the problem is to do with having no monitor defined...

Comment: Right click on desktop and go to "display settings". There set Resolution to 1920:1200 (16:10). It becomes full screen.

Answer (score 2):

From the menu bar,

1. Click on "Devices." You will see  "Insert Guest Additions CD Image" option there.
2. "Insert Guest Additions CD Image" inserts a disk image on a virtual CD on your machine.
3. This virtual CD usually starts automatically with autorun, but if not, just go to "Computer" and launch the "VboxWindowsAdditions" exe file on the CD and follow the installation

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below steps works for me ---

Upgraded linux-image and headers `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.11.0-15-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic` (Perhaps virtual would work just as well as the generic one.):

Installed linux-image-extras with the hyperv-drivers: 
`sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual`

Set video mode (Pretty much what you already did):
Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1680x1050"` in /etc/default/grub.
Update grub: `sudo update-grub`

Reboot

refer below link for more detail https://askubuntu.com/questions/384602/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution

Answer (score 0):

First, type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc perl make
```

After this, you can follow these steps:

1. Click on "Devices." You will see "Insert Guest Additions CD Image" option there.
2. "After clicking a Dialog Box opens up, Click on Run.
3. After it is installed, restart the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem. I did it manually from the ubuntu terminal, here are the steps:-

```
1 cd /media
2  ls
3  mkdir device  cdrom1
4  sudo mkdir device  cdrom1
5  ls
6  sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom1
7  cd cdrom1/
8  ls
9  sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

10  sudo reboot

This worked for me.